# ASP.NET call hangs on async await

Tags: asp.net, async-await, iis-express

My calls to a Google API from an API Controller in IIS express hang indefinitely when called sequentially using async await.

```
var id = CreateDocument("My Title").Result;

async Task<string> CreateDocument(string title)
{
    var file = new GData.File { Title = title };
    // Stepping over this line in the debugger never returns in IIS Express.
    file = await Service.Files.Insert(file).ExecuteAsync();
    return file.Id;
}
```

It does not hang calling the same method from a test console app.

The same logic also does not hang IIS Express when called using the corresponding synchronous method instead.

```
var id = CreateDocument("My Title");

string CreateDocument(string title)
{
    var file = new GData.File { Title = title };
    // This has no problem
    file = Service.Files.Insert(file).Execute();
    return file.Id;
}
```

Where should I look for the defect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The defect is here:

```
var id = CreateDocument("My Title").Result;
```

As I explain on my blog, [you should not block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Instead of `Result`, use `await`:

```
var id = await CreateDocument("My Title");
```

Comment: Interestingly, I'd briefly skimmed your blog post before posting here. At first glance it appeared to me that it didn't apply to my situation. I see of course now that it does. The defect is no single line, obviously, but I appreciate your point. At some point the async has to be unwrapped, in this case it just happens to be by the provider that understands the enforced single-threaded nature of the environment. Is that accurate?

Comment: It's also ironic that I was trying to get a grasp on this very thing when I first looked at async methods on API controllers. I was already aware of the single-threaded nature, and of course I rely on it for other reasons. So it occurred to me there must be an ultimate "sink" somewhere for the async methods.

Comment: @shannon: Technically, it's not single-threaded. But you're correct in that ASP.NET understands what the `Task` return type means, and will not finish the response until that task completes.